# how to find element by webdriver with class name when there are more than one element with the same class name?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

i use webdriver for instagram bot. I want to click on my follower but there is more than one element with the ((-nal3)) class name. this element does not have id or name or anything else.

```
'''
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gmFkV').click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('-nal3').click()
'''
```

i didn't get any error but driver doesen't click on element

Comment: By finding its parent class then from parent class selecting that class. Or by finding ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('-nal3')[1].click()
```

You can just use the index and use find_elements.